# How do I create a PrintDocumentAdapter to print an image using Android 4.4 print API's

Tags: android, printing

How do I create a PrintDocumentAdapter to print an image using Android 4.4 print print API's. I know you could use a PrintHelper to print bitmaps easily, but I need to access the PrintJob so as to query it's status at a later time.

When I use PrintHelper to submit a printJob, the return type is void.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/ShinobiControls/bitesize-kitkat/blob/master/PrintShop/PrintShop.md
it's a good example how to create custome PrintDocumentAdapter

Comment: is that site searching the printer using wifi or bluetooth?